# Generate a Chocolatey checksum from downloaded msi

Tags: chocolatey

Chocolatey documentation for creating packages says that checksum is now required.

The package i am installing is a downloaded msi set with $url. 
The docs say you can use checksum.exe (choco install checksum) and use

`checksum -t sha256 -f path\to\file`

if i understand this correctly, this will generate a checksum against the file.

so, how do i do this against the msi that gets downloaded?

I can hardcode the checksum from the current msi, but if the underlying msi changes (but the url stays the same) then my checksum won't validate during install.

I would leave checksum out entirely, but Chocolatey now appears to require it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The checksum is used for a safety reason: Is the downloaded file really the file you want to install? But if you trust the provider of the file, you can tell choco to ignore the checksum with the `--ignore-checksums` command-line option:

```
choco install <package> --ignore-checksums
```

Note: If you can use PowerShell, the checksum can also be generated using the `Get-FileHash` cmdlet:

```
Get-FileHash -Path "path\to\file" -Algorithm SHA256
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different topics being asked about here, so I wanted to make sure that each is covered.

Firstly, Moderators of packages submitted to Chocolatey Community Repository make a number of checks.  With regard to checksums, the guidance is that checksums for an installer/zip/etc are **required** when the download happens over HTTP, and that checksums are **recommended** when the download happens over HTTPS.  In most cases, for new package submissions, Moderators (myself included) will request that checksums be added to package installation script, regardless of whether they happen over HTTP or HTTPS.

Secondly, a checksum is used to ensure that the file that is downloaded at runtime is the same as the one that the package maintainer expected it to be when the package was created.  This is a security feature, and when Chocolatey finds that the checksum differs between the file that is downloaded, and what was expected, it will not proceed with the installation.  There can be a number of reasons "why" the checksum is different.  Some of those reasons are covered in this blog post:

https://www.gep13.co.uk/blog/chocolatey-error-hashes-do-not-match

> Firstly, some packages (like Google Chrome) don't included versioned URL's for their application installer. As a result, you can only ever download the Chrome installer from one location, namely https://dl.google.com/tag/s/dl/chrome/install/googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi. As a result, whenever Google push out a new version of Chrome, which happens quite frequently, the most recent package version of Chrome on Chocolatey.org is immediately broken.
>
> The second way that checksums will break is if vendor "change" the application installer once it has been published, without changing the version number.

The latter reason is unfortunate, and there isn't much that can be done, aside from generating a new package version, that would need to use the [package fix version notation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/create-packages#package-fix-version-notation) to create a new package version (this is due to a package version being immutable, meaning it can't change, once it is approved).

For the former, when there is actually a new application version, and the file at the end of the URL is actually a new one, then the request would be to create a new package version, with the updated version number.  In this new package, you would include the new checksum value.

The final point that I wanted to make clear is that the checksum is generated and placed into the package, at the point in time that the package is created, and submitted to chocolatey.org.  It is done as you mentioned with, for example, the checksum.exe tool.  At installation time, Chocolatey then validates this checksum against the file that it downloads.  There are mechanisms in place, for example [AU](https://chocolatey.org/docs/automatic-packages#automatic-updater-au), that can help with automating this process.  This might be something that you want to look into.